# How do I map a `datetime-local` form control value to an epoch time property and back in Angular Reactive Forms?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, datetime-local

I have an underlying data object that represents a `timestamp` property as a `number` representing milliseconds since Epoch.

```js
   export class Activity {
      constructor(
        public timestamp: number=0,
      ) {}
    }
```

I have a form with a FormControl for that form input field.

```js
  activityForm = new FormGroup({
    timestamp: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
    ]),
  });
```

I want to use the HTML `datetime-local` type to view and edit this field (where "local" is UTC)

```html
<input 
    class="form-control" 
    type="datetime-local" 
    id="inputTimestamp" 
    formControlName="timestamp"
/>
```

A `datetime-local` control expects, and produces, the date time as an ISO String, not an epoch timestamp.

I have two functions defined in my component;

```js
toDatetime(timestamp: number) { return new Date(timestamp).toISOString().slice(0, 16);}
```

and

```js
fromDatetime(datetime: string) { return new Date(datetime).getTime(); }
```

How do I hook these up to the form field to do two-way conversion? Or can it only be done during `ngOnInit()` and `onSubmit()`?

**Update***:
In an ideal world, I'd like to simply save `this.activityForm.values` in my onSubmit() function, expecting that `timestamp` is accurately calculated and saved, without manually copying object properties.

Comment: when do you want to use `toDatetime` and `fromDatetime` exactly...?

Comment: @Andres2142, in an ideal world, I'd like to simply save `this.activityForm.values` in my `onSubmit()` function, expecting that `timestamp` is accurately saved, without manually copying object properties.